# Smoke animation, color is not changing?

Tags: animation, smoke-simulation, color

Hello i wanted to include a smoke animation for a render.
I have watched a lot of videos about the smoke animation and how to change the color but it is not working for me.
suspiciously the standart smoke is also black instead of grey, and it stays that way.

Here are the things i tried, maybe i´ve done something wrong:

-changing the color of the smoke of the flow object
-changing the color in the materials (I heard that doesnt works anyways since 2.79)
-changing the color in the compositor.
-edit: i actually got it halfway working by only changing one notes color input but that is not the result i want + it is supposed to work otherways

Thank you, this is really bothering me as it is supposed to be working.

[image: just black smoke instead of grey one]
[image: still black smoke, color is set to red]
[image: halfway working but inconvenient and not good lookin^^]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the color of both Volume Scatter AND Volume Absorption.
Also, you might obtain better'n'nicer control of your coloring by using a color ramp + the density attribute plugged in :

[image]

Comment: Yea well I tried plugging in both but thats just not working...
I ll post another picture where I tried your exact way

Comment: Have you lighted up your smoke? It needs a fair amount of light to show up. Maybe give us your .blend file so we can investigate.

Comment: Okay here you can download the link on Dropbox.
pls only use the file for solving this problem.
the layer should already be selected but it is in the bottem right of the first group. 

https://www.dropbox.com/s/5m0mw8i6c7s1wrr/The%20Summoning.blend1?dl=0

Comment: Obviously, it works: https://i.imgur.com/AVId19U.png  It's even better if you actually light it up, just a simple sun lamp gives that: https://i.imgur.com/gJDdVgq.png

Comment: Oh man well thank you a lot I never thought it would be a missing light, unfortunately the world lighting wasnt enough.
thank you for your help I appreciate it !

Comment: World lighting is never enough, especially if you use a simple color and uniform strength. A good lighting is contrasted and with more than one color. Always keep that in mind when you want to test some shading.

Answer (score 0):

also when I plugg in both the smoke stays Black

[image: Still Black]